# Laravel Route suddenly redirecting to / and not reaching Controller

Tags: php, laravel, controller, routes, laravel-5.6

I'm working on a Laravel 5.6 project and had to modify a route from GET to POST since we're submitting data to it now. The route currently looks like this:

```
Route::post('/templates/new', 'ProjectTemplateController@doCreate');
```

Pretty standard. When I try POSTing to this route, it redirects to `/` and the request never reaches the Controller. And it just started doing this out of the blue. I successfully was able to make 3 AJAX requests to this route which all created data as I would expect it to. But I removed the AJAX from the form and turned it into a normal form POST request and that was when it started to not work. Reverting the code back to the AJAX version didn't fix it, either.

There's nothing showing up in the logs when the redirect happens. I've made sure all of the auth middleware is functioning properly. I'm at a total loss for what's going on and could use some suggestions on what else I can look into. I can provide some more code samples if needed, just ask.

Edit: Also, should've mentioned I've tried all combinations of cache clear, route clear, dump autoload, etc. None of those work.

Edit 2: It's also worth mentioning that we have a 404 page and don't normally redirect on missing routes. If I typo this route it gives me the 404 page.

Comment: What happens if you change the route definition to `Route::post('/templates/new', function() { dd(request()->all()); })`. Are you able to see your request?

Comment: I would also run `php artisan route:clear` just in case you are caching your routes.

Comment: Added a couple other troubleshooting steps I did to the initial question. I tried the closure route method just now and that is also redirecting to `/` and not dumping the request

Comment: Could we see your `web.php`? Maybe another route is catching it, but quite strange if you changed nothing there as well.

Comment: There's some privileged information inside this file that I can't share, so I can't show you the entire file, but here's all the routes that have the same prefix: https://gist.github.com/Atrophius/5af87ed3fec733ff5e4677d70457e183

Comment: That'll be a tough one to debug. Maybe you could try xdebug and see exactly what's going on under the hood.

Comment: The *really* strange thing is that all the other routes in this file seem to be working. This is the only one that's failing.

Comment: Gotta ask: have you tried using a tool like Postman to try and make a POST request? Same thing?

Comment: I pulled the request from the network debugger and CURL'd it and got the same result. I haven't tried to manually construct a request against the route yet, but I'll give that a shot now.

Comment: I started building that request and realized what the problem was ... Missing CSRF token. Sigh. Always the simplest things. I also now need to go find out why that wasn't prompting properly about the token mismatch.

Comment: Wow. Indeed.. but it doesn't explain why your CURL failed though. Good luck with the exception.

Comment: CURL failed because I was literally just repeating the same broken request and didn't realize what was missing from it.

Answer (score 1):

The form didn't have a CSRF token.